# ExifTool command for batch copying .mp4 metadata from files to files?

Tags: command-line, video, batch, metadata, exiftool

I was surfing the web for a solution, but no thread was working for me. 
I've compressed multiple mp4 videoclips using HandBrake, thus loosing dateModified etc. 
What I would want to have is a command that copies the metadata from videos in a specific folder and pastes it to the compressed videos, which have the same names and are in a subfolder. 
DateCreated/DateModified would be sufficient enough for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706049/converting-video-formats-and-copying-tags-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Try
`exiftool -TagsFromFile SOURCEFILE -all:all DESTINATIONFILE`

As of version 11.39, exiftool's ability to copy tags in MP4/MOV video files has been greatly increased. The above command will copy any tag that it can in the sourcefile to the same tag in the destination file.

If you wish to process multiple files, take a look at exiftool's [`TagsFromFile` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#tagsFromFile-SRCFILE-or-FMT) and the `%d`, `%f`, and `%e` variables in the [`-w` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#w-EXT-or-FMT--textOut).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried the command, but it fails to update the information of the videofile and actually creates a third file. It's possible that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The backup file can be suppressed by adding `-overwrite_original`.  Maybe I misunderstood the data you wanted copied.  Try `exiftool -TagsFromFile SOURCEFILE -File*Date DESTINATIONFILE`  That will copy the file system dates from the source to the destination file.  These aren't embedded metadata, they're part of the file system, so no backup file will be created.